# How to serve ionic app by default on https instead of http?

Tags: ssl, ionic-framework, https

In Ionic 1, When I use **ionic serve**, would like to go `https://localhost:8100/#/app/profile` instead of `http://localhost:8100/#/app/profile`.

But when I use **htaccess** or **javascript** redirect, getting SSL connection error.

Is possible to run ionic apps on https?

Comment: This issue is addressed in this link 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1686

Comment: Yes. I've checked that link, but not works for me @scary_devil

Comment: This works for me: https://gist.github.com/justindmyers/266d169e97de20068f78

Comment: @Arul Did you solve this issue? I'm facing this issue to